# How to do the join two tables in postgresql on the datetime columns and that appear all registers of datetime in one only column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, join

I have two tables:

TABLE_MACHINE_1

```
datetime,            sensor_1
2017-10-01 21:00:00, 1.18047
2017-10-01 21:15:00, 1.18023
2017-10-01 21:30:00, 1.18059
2017-10-01 21:45:00, 1.18067
2017-10-01 22:00:00, 1.18056
2017-10-01 22:15:00, 1.18147
2017-10-01 22:30:00, 1.18104
2017-10-01 22:45:00, 1.18111
2017-10-01 23:00:00, 1.18103
2017-10-01 23:15:00, 1.18072
2017-10-01 23:30:00, 1.18083
2017-10-01 23:45:00, 1.18079
2017-10-02 00:00:00, 1.17996
2017-10-02 00:15:00, 1.17987
2017-10-02 00:30:00, 1.17968
2017-10-02 00:45:00, 1.17893
2017-10-02 01:00:00, 1.17852
2017-10-02 01:15:00, 1.17833
```

TABLE_MACHINE_2

```
datetime,            sensor_2
2017-10-01 21:45:00, 112.1
2017-10-01 22:00:00, 133.2
2017-10-01 22:15:00, 143.5
2017-10-01 22:30:00, 154.9
2017-10-01 22:45:00, 166.1
2017-10-01 23:30:00, 123.1
2017-10-01 23:45:00, 134.1
2017-10-02 00:00:00, 188.3
2017-10-02 01:00:00, 192.9
2017-10-02 01:15:00, 105.3
2017-10-02 01:30:00, 172.9
2017-10-02 01:45:00, 145.3
2017-10-02 02:00:00, 174.9
2017-10-02 02:15:00, 155.3
```

and I expected how the result:

JOIN EXPECTED

```
datetime,            sensor_1  sensor_2
2017-10-01 21:00:00, 1.18047,  NULL
2017-10-01 21:15:00, 1.18023,  NULL
2017-10-01 21:30:00, 1.18059,  NULL
2017-10-01 21:45:00, 1.18067,  112.1
2017-10-01 22:00:00, 1.18056,  133.2
2017-10-01 22:15:00, 1.18147,  143.5
2017-10-01 22:30:00, 1.18104,  154.9
2017-10-01 22:45:00, 1.18111,  166.1
2017-10-01 23:00:00, 1.18103,  NULL
2017-10-01 23:15:00, 1.18072,  NULL
2017-10-01 23:30:00, 1.18083,  123.1
2017-10-01 23:45:00, 1.18079,  134.1
2017-10-02 00:00:00, 1.17996,  188.3
2017-10-02 00:15:00, 1.17987,  105.3
2017-10-02 00:30:00, 1.17968,  NULL
2017-10-02 00:45:00, 1.17893,  NULL
2017-10-02 01:00:00, 1.17852,  NULL
2017-10-02 01:15:00, 1.17833,  NULL
2017-10-02 01:30:00, NULL   ,  172.9
2017-10-02 01:45:00, NULL   ,  145.3
2017-10-02 02:00:00, NULL   ,  174.9
2017-10-02 02:15:00, NULL   ,  155.3
```

but if I do FULL OUTER JOIN get:

FROM TABLE_MACHINE_1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_MACHINE_2 ON DATETIME

```
datetime,            sensor_1, datetime,            sensor_2
2017-10-01 21:00:00, 1.18047,  NULL,                NULL  
2017-10-01 21:15:00, 1.18023,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-01 21:30:00, 1.18059,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-01 21:45:00, 1.18067,  2017-10-01 21:45:00, 112.1
2017-10-01 22:00:00, 1.18056,  2017-10-01 22:00:00, 133.2
2017-10-01 22:15:00, 1.18147,  2017-10-01 22:15:00, 143.5
2017-10-01 22:30:00, 1.18104,  2017-10-01 22:30:00, 154.9
2017-10-01 22:45:00, 1.18111,  2017-10-01 22:45:00, 166.1
2017-10-01 23:00:00, 1.18103,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-01 23:15:00, 1.18072,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-01 23:30:00, 1.18083,  2017-10-01 23:30:00, 123.1
2017-10-01 23:45:00, 1.18079,  2017-10-01 23:45:00, 134.1
2017-10-02 00:00:00, 1.17996,  2017-10-02 00:00:00, 188.3
2017-10-02 00:15:00, 1.17987,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-02 00:30:00, 1.17968,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-02 00:45:00, 1.17893,  NULL,                NULL 
2017-10-02 01:00:00, 1.17852,  2017-10-02 01:00:00, 192.9
2017-10-02 01:15:00, 1.17833,  2017-10-02 01:15:00, 105.3
NULL,                NULL,     2017-10-02 01:30:00, 172.9 
NULL,                NULL,     2017-10-02 01:45:00, 145.3
NULL,                NULL,     2017-10-02 02:00:00, 174.9 
NULL,                NULL,     2017-10-02 02:15:00, 155.3
```

I need to solve it in one query in postgresql and I tried with full outer join clause unsuccess.

I have thought about the following solution but I cannot implement it because get error when I pass the variable "generate_series":

1. Create one variable to store the maximun day of each table.

   ```
     datetime_end := to_char(now()::date,'YYY-MM-DD');
   ```
2. Pass the variable to the following query:

   ```
     SELECT generate_series(
         timestamp without time zone '2017-10-01',
         timestamp without time zone datetime_end,
         '15 minute');
   ```

   3. To do LEFT JOIN the query before to the two tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FROM TABLE_MACHINE_1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_MACHINE_2 ON DATETIME

That is not valid SQL.

If you do the join with `USING` rather than `ON`, then it will merge the columns automatically.

```
select 
    datetime,
    t1.sensor_1,
    t2.sensor_2
from table_machine_1 t1
full outer join table_machine_2 t2 
    USING (datetime)
```

Comment: @GMB  Did you?  There is no error.  USING merges the join column(s), creating an unambiguous column in the result.

Comment: I just did, and I can see that you are right! +1 this answer learnt me something. Deleting my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

You want `full outer join`*and* `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.datetime, t2.datetime) datetime,
    t1.sensor_1,
    t2.sensor_2
from table_machine_1 t1
full outer join table_machine_2 t2 
    on t1.datetime = t2.datetime
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f5BkDuWkFgg7C7crSuVQop/0)**:

```
| datetime            | sensor_1 | sensor_2 |
| ------------------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2017-10-01 21:00:00 | 1.18047  |          |
| 2017-10-01 21:15:00 | 1.18023  |          |
| 2017-10-01 21:30:00 | 1.18059  |          |
| 2017-10-01 21:45:00 | 1.18067  | 112.1    |
| 2017-10-01 22:00:00 | 1.18056  | 133.2    |
| 2017-10-01 22:15:00 | 1.18147  | 143.5    |
| 2017-10-01 22:30:00 | 1.18104  | 154.9    |
| 2017-10-01 22:45:00 | 1.18111  | 166.1    |
| 2017-10-01 23:00:00 | 1.18103  |          |
| 2017-10-01 23:15:00 | 1.18072  |          |
| 2017-10-01 23:30:00 | 1.18083  | 123.1    |
| 2017-10-01 23:45:00 | 1.18079  | 134.1    |
| 2017-10-02 00:00:00 | 1.17996  | 188.3    |
| 2017-10-02 00:15:00 | 1.17987  |          |
| 2017-10-02 00:30:00 | 1.17968  |          |
| 2017-10-02 00:45:00 | 1.17893  |          |
| 2017-10-02 01:00:00 | 1.17852  | 192.9    |
| 2017-10-02 01:15:00 | 1.17833  | 105.3    |
| 2017-10-02 02:00:00 |          | 174.9    |
| 2017-10-02 01:30:00 |          | 172.9    |
| 2017-10-02 01:45:00 |          | 145.3    |
| 2017-10-02 02:15:00 |          | 155.3    |
```